# How to Avoid Facebook Graph API Limit with million of users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a WordPress webpage with posts retrieving from a public Facebook page. The FB page is not mine. However the problem is that I have millions of visitors on my Web page and every time a user visits the web page it make an API call to FB Page. Since facebook allows only a limited number of API calls in a time frame, My limit reaches instantly with such a huge number of visitors. Is there any solution to this problem. an idea in my mind is:

## 1. retrieve posts from Facebook and store them locally and display them every time a user visits. Is it possible? If Yes where to start ?

Or can we get more API calls by paying facebook or things like that. I am ready to pay as far as my API calls can be made sufficient for my needs.
I am open to any solution and would be very thankful for any help to resolve the problem.

Comment: you should never do that..always cache results, this will obviously hit api limits with lots of users. how to cache stuff is a bit broad for stackoverflow though. the best way may be to check the timestamp of the last api call when a user hits your page - if the timestamp is older than x minutes, do the api call to check for new items to store in your cache. btw, make sure the page owner knows about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this problem

#### Storing responses in database

You can add a middlepoint to your requests to Facebook API using your application. This would mean that you would have a database table which stores Facebook-related information, possibly along with a lifecycle time, like:

> facebook_data(user_id, lifecycle_time, ...)

Whenever you would theoretically need to send a request to Facebook API, you can check the database table to see whether the user already has a record in that table and whether it is still valid. If so, give this data to the user. If not, send an API request to Facebook and store the response in this table.

#### Storing responses in localStorage/memory/file

You can also store Facebook-related data in the localStorage of the web browser of the memory of an app or a file, or even a local database specific for each user. This would prevent a lot of communication and server load your app is issuing on your server(s).

#### Queueing user requests to be sent

If the Facebook-related data is not very urgent to your users, you can queue requests to be sent and send a single request instead of a request for each user's each visit. You can do this via a cron job.

#### Periodically sending requests to Facebook

You can group your users into batches and periodically update their values via Facebook and storing in your database.

#### Combination

Naturally, you can combine the approaches, for instance, you can store in local memory, file, or localStorage values and in the database in the same time, so first locally stored information is searched for, not needing even a request if it exists and is still valid. If not, then checking the database record and using that if it exists and is still valid. And if the data is not found in local resources, nor your database, then you can send an API request.